# log4j/slf4j breaks deploy to glassfish 4

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, logging, glassfish

I have an EJB project I'm deploying to Glassfish via eclipse, and the following line of code causes the deploy to break:

`Logger L = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IPersonDao.class);`

If I remove this line, it works fine.  I can leave the slf4j import statements and if I comment out this line, no problem.  If I enable this like, Glassfish gives an error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load the EJB module. DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB. ...

Why?  This makes no sense, and if I use either a log4j Logger or an slf4j Logger the deploy breaks.  Comment out that line, and it works.

What gives?

Here is the bean:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author martin
 */
@Stateless(name="HelloBean")
@LocalBean
@Remote
public class HelloBean {
    //private static Logger L = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloBean.class);

    public HelloBean(){
    //L.info("HelloBean created");
    }

    public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello";
    }
}
```

It works, but if I uncomment the logging lines it fails.

Here are the deps:

> org.slf4j
>   slf4j-api   1.7.12
>
> ch.qos.logback
>   logback-classic   1.0.13

Comment: Are there any other errors or warnings earlier in your startup log?  This kind of message usually suggests there was a failure earlier in startup.  (I've seen loggers cause issues where slf4j tries to wrap log4j which is trying to wrap slf4j, I'm wondering if you might be having a similar problem?)

Comment: No other errors, that's all.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Could you share your dependencies list? What jars do you have in your classpath. If you're using maven, it'll be nice if you post the dependencies section of your pom file.

Comment: See the edit, the deps are from my POM but are not getting put into my jar by maven.  I'm not sure how to get them on the classpath for GF?

Comment: The traditional way to do this is to place your ejb-jar in an EAR file, with your dependencies in the "lib/" directory of the EAR file. If you're trying to deploy a standalone ejb-jar then you will need to get your deps into the server class path.